# Magento 1.8 - Class 'Mage_Helloworld_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.8, helper, not-found

I can't access `System -> Configuration` in the backend anymore. I get the message `Class 'Mage_Helloworld_Helper_Data' not found`.

How can I debug this, I am new to magento.

---

I found a Module named "**HelloWorld**" in `app/code/local/Webkochshop`.

This is the snippet where the helper is at:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <Webkochshop_HelloWorld>
            <class>Webkochshop_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
        </Webkochshop_HelloWorld>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Comment: check your helpers tag in `Helloworld` module's `config.xml` file.

Comment: @kunj, Thank you kunj, thanks to you I was able to solve it, by changing `Webkochshop_HelloWorld` to the modules name in lowcase -> `helloworld`. I will accept your answer if you write one.

Comment: yes, maybe you have used `helloworld` in system configuration XML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <Webkochshop_HelloWorld>
            <class>Webkochshop_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
        </Webkochshop_HelloWorld>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

`Webkochshop_HelloWorld` should in `module="Webkochshop_HelloWorld"` OR change as per system config `module="helloworld"` in:

```
<global>
        <helpers>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Webkochshop_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
            </helloworld>
        </helpers>
    </global>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to change my code to this:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Webkochshop_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
        </helloworld>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

`helloworld` is the module name in lower case letters.